How to monitor an HTTP request made by playwright apirequest
I am trying to make an HTTP request using playwright
await page.GotoAsync(https://stackoverflow.com");
var http1 = await page.APIRequest.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com", new APIRequestContextOptions()
{
    IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true
});
await Task.Delay(10_000);

But something isn't working and I don't know what. I've tried to monitor the request in fiddler by setting the playwright proxy to localhost:8888, this captchas the normal playwright actions such as gotoasync but the apirequest doesn't appear. On the same vein I've tried in devtools network tab, again the normal browser automation shows but the apirequest.get seems to bypass the monitoring.
The request is made, I get the result of the request (status / source etc) but something is not being set in the request correctly to get the results expected, so I need to see the HTTP request to figure it out.
Is there any way to be able to inspect these requests?

What isn't working and what are you trying to achieve?

@ggorlen I want to see the HTTP request in dev tools network tab (or in fiddler) in order to debug the request and find out what I am doing wrong with the request

I see. I don't think these requests run in the browser context, but I'm not 100% sure offhand. Why not run the request in the browser context inside an Evaluate block so you can examine it? You should be able to debug the request in the current code too, since all the headers and data are right there, added explicitly, as far as I can tell.

since its a GET request all things are visible generally straight forward just the URL is passed.. may be you can try via postman and see its console and try adding those headers etc in playwright to see if it works that way like accept etc headers
